# How to find the sum of a row or column which has a specific value?

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to code a magic square problem. I have a 6 * 6 square and I know what the sum of each row or column supposed to be. It is sum = 6 * ((36 + 1) / 2). There are -1 occure at some places. We have to find out what it is supposed to be so that the magic square will be right.
I just need to know how to check if there is -1 and replace it with the correct number.

Here is the minimal code containing the error:

```
//to check if there is -1
int array[6][6];
sum = 6 * ((36 + 1) / 2)  
int i,j;
for (i=0; i<=6; i++)
    for (j=0; j<=6; j++)
       if(square[i][j] = -1)
       {
           square[i][j] = sum - (sum of the row or column where -1 was found)
       }
```

Comment: Inside your `j` loop keep a running column sum, e.g. `int rowsum = 0;` and `rowsum += square[i][j];` and then you have the `"sum of the row or column where -1 was found"` when the `j` loop completes.

Comment: Loop will overflow, it has to be 0 to 5 so i and j has to be “<6”

Answer (score 1):

The logic of your code is correct, the only problem I think you should be encountering is that in both of the loops (for 'i' and 'j') will run till i=6 and j=6, because as you may have studied that the indexes of the arrays (even in 2-d array) starts from 0 and ends with the index n-1 (n will be the length of the array)

suppose I have array as a[3]a[3], So the indexing will be like this

`a[0][0]  a[0][1]  a[0][2] 
 a[1][0]  a[1][1]  a[1][2]
 a[2][0]  a[2][1]  a[2][2]`